# Insert into DATE column of MySQL with PHP from textbox

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert

I have a form with different fields and all is working fine using PHP and HTML.
And have a database in MySQL.
I have two columns names are `from` and `to`
and form fields like:

INPUT type is `TEXT`
Database Field datatype is `DATE`

`From: <input class="smltab" type="text" id="from" name="from"/>`

`To:  <input class="smltab" type="text" id="to2" name="to2"/>`

The problem is the insert query stuck on `from` and `to` fields.
And then the entry in Database is `0000-00-00` and `0000-00-00`

INSERT QUERY:

```
 $db->Execute("insert into leave_app (leave_type,name,eid,dept,desig,from,to) 
     values('".$leave."' , '".$name."' , '".$empid."' , '".$dept."' , '".$desg."' , '".$from."' , '".$to."')");
```

Comment: where is your query and what is the format of the input dates ?

Comment: you didn't add "from and "to" fields in your query

Comment: I have checked the entries after putting '23-12-2014' and '2014-12-23' But the Database is still showing 0000-00-00. Sorry Sorry NEW QUERY is:  $db->Execute("insert into leave_app (leave_type,name,eid,dept,desig,from,to)
values('".$leave."' , '".$name."' , '".$empid."' ,  '".$dept."' , '".$desg."' , '".$from."' , '".$to."')");

Comment: When using `2014-12-23` for `to` or `from` will result in an `0000-00-00` then I'm pretty sure that you have an error somewhere else in your code. You might do an `echo "insert into leave_app (leave_type,name,eid,dept,desig,from,to) values('".$leave."' , '".$name."' , '".$empid."' , '".$dept."' , '".$desg."' , '".$from."' , '".$to."')";` right before the `$db->Execute`, and show that output here.

Answer (score 0):

MySql database will take only yyyy-mm-dd format only if your text not that format convert before insert

```
$from = date('Y-m-d',strtottime($from));
$to = date('Y-m-d',strtottime($to));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this..**

Mysql database date format `yyyy-mm-dd`

```
 $fromdate=$_POST['from'];
 $todate=$_POST['to'];
 $from = date('Y-m-d',strtottime($fromdate));
 $to = date('Y-m-d',strtottime($todate));

 $db->Execute("insert into leave_app (leave_type,name,eid,dept,desig,from,to) values('".$leave."' , '".$name."' , '".$empid."' , '".$dept."' , '".$desg."' , '".$from."' , '".$to."')");
```

Answer (score -1):

try it

```
$(function(){
    $("#departuredate").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
    $("#arrivaldate").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }).bind("change",function(){
        var minValue = $(this).val();
        minValue = $.datepicker.parseDate("yy-mm-dd", minValue);
        minValue.setDate(minValue.getDate());
        ("#arrivaldate").datepicker( "option", "minDate", minValue );
    })
});
```

Htlml code

```
  <div class="tmInput">
     <span>Check In Date</span>
     <input type="text" name="arrivaldate" id="arrivaldate" data-constraints="@NotEmpty @Required @Date" />
  </div>     
  <div class="tmInput ">
     <span>Check Out Date</span>
     <input type="text" name="departuredate" id="departuredate" data-constraints="@NotEmpty @Required @Date" />
  </div>
```

Comment: Whenever you suggest to use a 3rd party library, you should tell which one. While it might be obvious that `$` is jQuery it might be not obvious anymore from which library `datepicker` is. The same is with `data-constraints="@NotEmpty @Required @Date"`. And check your answer after posting if all formatting are working.

Comment: how to right this question in this tag can you explain me

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand what you are asking. You want to know how to answer the question of the OP by only using PHP and MySQL, without any JS?